# NSBundle path for resource return nil in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsbundle

I've a `bgs.bundle` which contains 20 images, I'm trying to load image_file.

```
NSString *bpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgs" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bpath error:NULL];
for (NSString *fileName in files) {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"nil"];
        if (filePath){
                NSLog(filePath);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"file path is null");
        }
```

`filePath` is always null, I've also printed `fileName` which is working fine.
What can be the problem with my code or there is some other way to load files from bundle?

Comment: is there a reason you set nil for ofType ?

Comment: yes, bundle contains .png as well as .jpg

Comment: is filePath nil when u set ofType to either of png or jpg ?

Comment: yes, it is always nil, I've also tried to ofType to png

Comment: Why are you trying to get the image file from the main bundle instead of your `bgs.bundle`?

Comment: coz its not device specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main issue is that you attempt to load `fileName` from the main bundle instead of the `bgs.bundle`.

Change your code like this:

```
NSString *bpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgs" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:bpath error:NULL];
for (NSString *fileName in files) {
     NSString *filePath = [bpath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
     NSLog(@"filePath = %@", filePath);
}
```

Another option would be to get an `NSBundle` for `bgs.bundle`.

```
NSString *bpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bgs" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSBundle bgsBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bpath];
```

Now you can use `bgsBundle` as needed. Example:

```
NSString *filePath = [bgsBundle pathForResource:@"someImage" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: how to get path from bgsBundle ?

Comment: The same way you do for `mainBundle`. See my updated answer.